# Proving that $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$ for a given set of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity, solution-verification

I found the following problem:

> Let $X$ be the set of continuous functions from $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$. For $x,y\in X$ define $d(x,y)$ by
> $$d(x,y) = \int_a^b |x(t) - y(t)|\, dt.$$
> Prove that $(X, d)$ is a metric space.

So I solved it as usual. I checked that for $x,y,z\in X$:

1. $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$,
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$,
3. $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

To prove 1. we know that $\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt =0$ if and only if $f(t)=0$ for all $t\in [a,b]$ provided that $f(t)$ is continuous. Hence
for any $x,y\in X$, we have
$$d(x,y) = \int_a^b |x(t) - y(t)|\, dt = 0 \quad \iff \quad  |x(t) - y(t)| = 0 \quad\text{for all } t\in [a,b]$$
which implies that $x=y$.

But then I was thinking, what if $a=b$? If so,
$$\int_a^a |x(t) - y(t)|\, dt =0$$
and this works for any $x,y\in X$.

Would this imply that $d$ is not a metric and therefore $X$ is not a metric space?

What I am missing here? Do I need to assume that $a<b$ in the problem in order to make $X$ a metric space?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the assumption $a<b$ is needed as you describe.

Comment: Yes definitely, you must assume it . And more over ,it is given [a,b] so we can think always a<b

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback. :)